# How to get the client IP address after got connection lost in twisted

Tags: python, ip, twisted

I know we can get the client (host) IP after connection has been established because at that time we will have transport attribute:

```
self.transport.getPeer()
```

but how do I get the IP address of the client in twisted TCP server when it lost connection to the server, as in after it got disconnected.

Comment: Can't you do it during connection, store it as an attribute then just read it later

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its a little late for that. I suggest you save this information when you have it. For example:

```
class YourProtocol(protocol.Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self._peer = self.transport.getPeer()

    def connectionLost(self):
        print 'Lost connection from', self._peer
```

Comment: Thank you , for you answer . are you sure cant we get at the time of connection lost

Comment: Ok I was wrong the first time. Actually self.transport.getPeer() call works fine for me from connectionLost() callback. I tested this for TCP connection. 
I can also see from the implementation that you would not have self.protocol attribute in case of DatagramProtocol subclass, so for UDP. Is this your case?

Comment: exceptions.TypeError: connectionLost() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Answer (score 2):

While this has already been answered, i thought i would quickly add mine so i do not forget this in the future... As we know, the docs for Twisted are .. well twisted...

```
def connectionLost(self):
    ip, port = self.transport.client
    print ip
    print port
```

By using the above, you can then simply match the ip/port against what ever database or means you have of keeping track of clients.

I ended up finding by using `print vars(self.transport)` and seeing the client object in the output/console... using classic php debugging here