# Twisted : How to know which client has closed the connection

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.client

This is a follow-up to my previous question.

I am building a simple client server program using ´twisted´ package in Python.

I would like to keep a record of which client has joined and closed the connection.

Suppose, if Client B closes the connection, I would like to print at the server "Client B has closed the connection"

Here is the code I am using :

```
factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = Echo
PortNo = 8000
reactor.listenTCP(PortNo,factory)

reactor.run()



def connectionLost(self, reason): 

print "Connection lost"
```

Any idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278555/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-after-got-connection-lost-in-twisted).

Answer (score 0):

The connection which was lost is the one associated with the protocol instance referenced by the `self` argument to `connectionLost`.

With a normal factory (like `ServerFactory`, as you are using) there is a one to one relationship between connections and protocol instances.