# Twisted reverse proxy block some ips

Tags: python, twisted, ipv4, blacklist

I've built a simple reverse proxy using twisted so that i can block some requests coming to my server. Checking the URI works fine, but I would also like to add an black-list of ipv4.

How can i check what ip is connecting to my proxy and eventually refuze connection?

Here's my code so far:

```
class BadURL(Resource):
    def render(self, request):
    return ""
class HTTPSReverseProxyResource(proxy.ReverseProxyResource, object):
    def getChild(self, path, request):

    if some logic:
            return BadURL()
    child = super(HTTPSReverseProxyResource, self).getChild(path, request)
    return HTTPSReverseProxyResource(child.host, child.port, child.path,
                                     child.reactor)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('-c', type=str)
    ap.add_argument('-k', type=str)
    ns = ap.parse_args()

    myProxy = HTTPSReverseProxyResource('localhost', 4443, '')

    site = server.Site(myProxy)


    reactor.listenTCP(8080, site, interface='192.168.58.1')
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: I think this has been already answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278555/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-after-got-connection-lost-in-twisted)

Comment: in that post uses self.transport but in ReverseProxyResource class there is no "transport" (exceptions.AttributeError: 'HTTPSReverseProxyResource' object has no attribute 'transport')